# Elasticsearch - what is better: query several fields or single combined field?

Tags: elasticsearch

**Declaimer**: Possible duplicate of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213092/what-is-better-one-big-field-or-many-small), not sure...

Let's assume I have something similar to [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/) (e.g. catalog of movies) and I want to store it in Elasticsearch.

Single Movie record contains Title, Description, and Categories (strings, e.g. "Children", "Action", etc).

Let's assume that users allowed to search a free text, which can be everything: words from title, from description or from categories (e.g. "movie for children").

I wondering, from search performance perspective, what is more efficient: to query on each of the fields, or to create a special big field which is a concatenation of all of the fields and then to query only on it.

Comment: First of all, I don't think IMDB is searching across all fields. Internally, it might be performing separate searches and aggregating the data in the results page from different document types.

if you are doing term search, then you can have a copy_to field per mapping type in which you can dump the attributes on which you want to allow the search on. Please note that _all will no longer be available from v6. This way, if you end up adding additional attributes that are not searchable, they wont necessarily have to be indexed.

Comment: Having multiple fields will make it difficult for you to identify which field should be searched and you will end up having to search all searchable fields anyway.